# What happens with uninitialized fields?

Tags: c#

I've read these SO questions:

- [what-happens-with-unused-class-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415315/what-happens-with-unused-class-properties)
- [do-unassigned-properties-take-up-memory-in-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457588/do-unassigned-properties-take-up-memory-in-a-class)
- [does-declaration-in-c-sharp-allocate-memory-or-is-it-the-new-operator-that-alloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824971/does-declaration-in-c-sharp-allocate-memory-or-is-it-the-new-operator-that-alloc/15825548#15825548)
- [memory-allocation-of-class-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520378/memory-allocation-of-class-objects)

I'm very sorry, that I ask this question. But its still not clear.

Until now, I understood, uninitialized fields like this:

```
private MyClass Object;
```

Are getting their default value. And I learned that the default value of an object is null.

But I don't know if it's like this:

```
private MyClass Object = null;
//or like
private MyClass Object = new Class() { MemberOne = null, MemberTwo = null };
```

Or is it completely something other?

Comment: It requires storage.  Memory is a resource too.  You have a lot of it so unless you create millions of objects of this class you'll never notice.

Comment: It will take its fair share of resource/memory every time the method is called. If its not necessary why use it in first place

Comment: You can read Eric Lippert's answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15527574/7974050

and 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825548/7974050

to understand better.

Comment: You can write a simple program to test these sort of things. For example, something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nGOtVD. You can see that attempting to check whether the field's properties (e.g. `MemberOne`) is null fails because the field itself is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How [Jeff Bridgman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945456/jeff-bridgman) wrote it is

```
private MyClass Object; 
//Is equal
private MyClass Object = null;
```

You can test it by yourself in this [dotnetfiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/nGOtVD).

Answer (score 1):

Unused field consumes memory for each instance of a class. They are simply initialized automatically to their default values.

Comment: For classes the default is basically `null`.

Comment: @DamienFlury For classes, the default **is** `null`, isn't it? No "basically" about it.

Comment: @TannerSwett When an instance is assigned to `null`, its value in the dictionary is just a reference to `null`, therefore a `null-reference`. I was afraid that just calling it's default value `null` is theoretically not 100% correct, because value types and reference types interact differently according to their values. Value types always have a default value, while reference types don't **really** have one.